# Send Telnet command inside a SSH Tunnel

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, router, tunnel

I want to connect my personal computer to some routers via Telnet, for managing them.

Actually, my routers is in another network. I open the console, make a SSH connection to the Main Mahcine, and then make a Telnet.

I want to cover that intermediate connection with a SSH tunnel, and directly make a telnet binding for example, the port 2222 to the remote server:22

Finding in Google, I see a easy way to create SSH Tunnel

`ssh -f user@server -L 2222:server:22`

-L Binds the local port to the remote machine:port
-f force to stay background

But now, I don't know how can I send telnet through the SSH tunnel, how can I reference the source, using the tunnel?

Thank you.

Comment: if you point your telnet client to localhost:2222 it will be sent through your tunnel to port 22 on the server, but I don't think thats what you want, since telnet cannot talk ssh.

Comment: What you say it's correct. In other words, I want to emulate the telnet connection from the remote host

Comment: I think you are a little confused on how tunneling works. you describe a tunnel between two ports (neither of which is the ssh port 22), and then tell ssh to tunnel between them, using ssh ports, so you never tell ssh to use ssh, you tell it,'I want to tunnel telnet from local:2222 to server:23'. but all this seems futile since you are telneting into the routers, not the server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since it's a local port, you can reference it using `localhost`.

Let's assume that the main machine is called `main`, and the router behind this machine is called `router`. The following command sequence should work:

```
ssh -f user@main -L 2222:router:23 -N
telnet localhost 2222
```

Given that the IP address of `main` is `192.168.1.2`, and the IP address of `router` is `10.0.1.2`, this is the command sequence to use:

```
ssh -f user@192.168.1.2 -L 2222:10.0.1.2:23 -N
telnet localhost 2222
```

Comment: But sending telnet to local host, where I specify the IP of the specific router I want to connect to?

Comment: Updated my solution with more details (:

Comment: It Works! Thank you yjwong. I just edited your answer adding `-N` to the command line in order to work.

Comment: What is the telnet behavior if the remote server is down?